# ForeignKey ListField serialization on rest_framework with django-nonrel

Tags: django, mongodb, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-nonrel

I have a class called Collection

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    videos = ListField(models.ForeignKey(Video))
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    objects = MongoDBManager()
```

with a videos property that is a ListField of Video object ForeignKeys.

When I try to Serialize Collection object on rest_framework y create my serializer:

```
class CollectionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    videos = VideoSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Collection
        fields = ('name','description','videos', 'pub_date')
```

But i get this error:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `VideoSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `unicode` instance.
Original exception text was: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'name'.
```

Despite using *VideoSerializer* i have used *serializers.StringRelatedField* and then I get an array of objectids as strings. But what I want is the serializer to get that array of oobjectids and convert them to Vido Objects and serialize them.

The Object on MongoDB looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "ibiza",
    "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5564c86e424f777f81d8f3ec"
    },
    "description": "ertertertre",
    "videos": [
        {
            "$oid": "5564d0c8424f7704aea99813"
        }
    ],
    "pub_date": {
        "$date": "2015-05-27T12:20:57.000Z"
    },
    "name": "Ibiza"
}
```

**NOTE:** I want to avoid using EmbeddedModelField

Comment: You forgot to include your `VideoSerializer` in your question, that's the one raising the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are passing a string (`unicode` type) to DRF but you are expecting DRF to turn it into a nested representation. Without anything extra, DRF is not possible to do this, as it's way out of the general scope that it tries to maintain.

[Django REST framework Mongoengine](https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine) on the other hand is perfectly fine with handling the abstraction layer, and it's recommended for those using Django REST framework with Mongoengine.

Without an abstraction layer, you are going to be forced to [create a custom field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) that converts the object ids into the actual objects, and then serializes them into the nested representations.

Comment: Yes i had a look of the django-rest-framework-mongoengine but i wanted to mantain the original rest_framework. I will try the mongoengine version one, i hope the change will be easy.. thanks.